# Don't repeat yourself: same SQL query, but two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, union-all

I have an SQL query with exact the same code, but two different tables (AUDIT_TRAIL_ARCHIVE and AUDIT_TRAIL). I use "UNION ALL" to have one result.

Good programmers use ["Don't repeat yourself"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Good programmers avoid WET (write everything twice).

Howto rewrite this code with "Don't repeat yourself" principle?

```
SELECT REPLACE (ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '')
 FROM    AUDIT_TRAIL_ARCHIVE AU
   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT RSS_USER_NAME
         FROM RSS_USER
        WHERE RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
              AND ADD_INFO_MASTER LIKE '%__47__UPN=%@richemont.com%') FALSCH
   ON REPLACE (AU.ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '') =
         FALSCH.RSS_USER_NAME
WHERE     AU.RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
   AND AU.TABLE_NAME = 'rss_user'
   AND AU.ACTION = 'Insert'
   AND AU.ENTITY_KEY LIKE 'rss_user_name=CN=%'
   AND AU.ORIGIN != 'RSS'
UNION ALL
SELECT REPLACE (ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '')
 FROM    AUDIT_TRAIL AU
   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT RSS_USER_NAME
         FROM RSS_USER
        WHERE RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
              AND ADD_INFO_MASTER LIKE '%__47__UPN=%@richemont.com%') FALSCH
   ON REPLACE (AU.ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '') =
         FALSCH.RSS_USER_NAME
WHERE     AU.RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
   AND AU.TABLE_NAME = 'rss_user'
   AND AU.ACTION = 'Insert'
   AND AU.ENTITY_KEY LIKE 'rss_user_name=CN=%'
   AND AU.ORIGIN != 'RSS'
```

Comment: What is your goal here: to use dynamic sql, e.g. same sql but diff. tables or rewrite the query as in Florin's example?

Comment: @fyodor78 The first solution is not always the best. Of course you can join the tables BEFORE Selecting - but why would you build a temporary table of 100.000 rows, when you want to retrieve one row from each? See at dynamic SQL, create a procedure, build up a query string and reuse that procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
SELECT REPLACE (ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '')
 FROM    (select * --or relevant columns
          from AUDIT_TRAIL_ARCHIVE AU
          union all
          select * 
          from AUDIT_TRAIL AU
           ) AU
   INNER JOIN
      (SELECT RSS_USER_NAME
         FROM RSS_USER
        WHERE RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
              AND ADD_INFO_MASTER LIKE '%__47__UPN=%@richemont.com%') FALSCH
   ON REPLACE (AU.ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '') =
         FALSCH.RSS_USER_NAME
WHERE     AU.RSS_NAME = 'rmad'
   AND AU.TABLE_NAME = 'rss_user'
   AND AU.ACTION = 'Insert'
   AND AU.ENTITY_KEY LIKE 'rss_user_name=CN=%'
   AND AU.ORIGIN != 'RSS'
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you wouldn't be able to filter the two selects that you `UNION ALL` by values from the rest of the query?

Comment: No. Actually, the answer filters the two queries in the where clause: `AU.TABLE_NAME = 'rss_user'` . AU is the alias for the union all part. The filter can be pushed by the engine to filter before doing the join.

Answer (score 0):

Good programmers use "Don't repeat yourself" principle. Good programmers avoid WET (write everything twice).

Heh. I like that. subtle.

also, I'm probably being way too basic but would something like this work:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE <name_of_procedure> [ (<ENTITY_KEY_variable>) ]
IS
    <ENTITY_KEY=ENTITY_KEY_variable>
BEGIN
    <your code goes here>

    [EXCEPTION
        exception_section]
END [procedure_name];
```

edit: i see from the first posted answer I fell for a trolling? silly me.

Comment: @@Bryan Devaney: Your code will never work in Oracle. Please revise.

Comment: sorry, popped up under sql, thought it was mysql... 

updating answer now

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can not. SQL is compiled language (even if it looks like scripting) and Oracle remembers OBJECT_IDs the query depends. Each half of the query has different dependencies, different "bytecode" and different execution plan.

You can

- Use tablespace partitioning. Then you would have only one table. Queries against live data could be restricted using "select * from AUDIT_TRAIL partition ACTIVE".
- Use query factoring like

  ```
  WITH AU AS
  (SELECT * from AUDIT_TRAIL union all select * from AUDIT_TRAIL_ARCHIVE)
  SELECT REPLACE (ENTITY_KEY, 'rss_user_name=CN=', '')
  FROM AU JOIN ...
  ...
  ```

  But I'm not sure whether in this case will Oracle guarantee the same efficiency of execution plan.